# Prevent Dialog from scrolling to top of page Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

Whenever I open the Material-UI Dialog, the page gets scrolled to the top.

Here is an approximate repro of my project:

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-voice-q14h4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same issue, try setting the prop `disableEnforceFocus` to true.